# How to make Typescript interface property to be depended on another property

Tags: typescript

Consider an example:

```
type Colors = {
  light: 'EC3333' | 'E91515'
  dark: '#100F0F' | '140F0F' 
}

interface Palette {
  colorType: keyof Colors
  color: Colors[keyof Colors]
}
```

is there any way that type of the `color` property becomes depended on `colorType` property?

meaning - when I choose colorType `light`, `color` type should become `'EC3333' | 'E91515'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't represent `Palette` as a single non-generic `interface`, but you can make it a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of each desired pairing of `colorType` and `color`:

```
type Palette = {
    colorType: "light";
    color: "EC3333" | "E91515";
} | {
    colorType: "dark";
    color: "#100F0F" | "140F0F";
}
```

You can even make the compiler compute this for you from `Colors` by [mapping over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the keys of `Colors` and then immediately [indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into the resultant mapped object type:

```
type Palette = { [K in keyof Colors]: {
  colorType: K
  color: Colors[K]
} }[keyof Colors];
```

You can verfiy via IntelliSense that this results in the same type as before, with the advantage that it will automatically update if you change `Colors`.

---

Armed with this union type, you can start using `Palette` and seeing the constraint enforced and understood:

```
const badPalette: Palette = {
  colorType: "dark",
  color: "E91515" 
} // error!

const goodPalette: Palette = {
  colorType: "dark",
  color: "140F0F" 
} // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJwM5QLxQN4CgpQICWA5gBbABcUA5AKIwDMzjNUAPrXQJwCMArAJr4oAEwCGyANbUaAYl4AGRQDFVbTjV4AWVetwBfXLlCQoABXEIIwYNCzYoAbQDSUIgDsoUiCDgAzWEQUVABdajwCAGNg5AAVcAhqFxEYpGRqeHTUV1DDKAMnHz9ArJDQgG5jAHoAKihTaEtrW3scEWjYhMhqACJicmBeqoJO9L6GFkZejihengEBYfzOSNG0lG6kuYlpZdGoDYy5hWU1FRnOXp09C6qDKFrq4xiPVGAoACNxUWabO2of1amHaY02iT6uykvQANKlYhM+IJ+DN8tVqlAIMhkCgAIQvOBvD4kOBwX5Wf7bIF2EFrI5bSGSaFwsHHa66c6oh7oqBwKTiEBAA)